# iOS - NSJSONSerializer parsing error for JSON Arrays

Tags: ios, json, rest, afnetworking-2, arrays

I'm using `AFNetworking 2.0` to call an REST API with returns an valid `JSONArray` like:

```
[{"myattr": "asdf"}, {"myattr": "jklo"}]
```

I parse my `responseObject` with this loc:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

The weird thing is that my `jSONArray` (looked up in the debugger) contains two objects but the serializer throws a parsing error. What happens is that some of the inner objects attributes are stripped of their ticks. So for example I see:

```
[{attr: "asdf", attr2: "jklo", "attr3": "tzze"}, ...]
```

The odd thing is here, that some of the attributes keep their ticks!

After all the only idea I have is (except that this whole thing is buggy) that the serializer doesn't anticipate the `JSONArray` but an `JSONObject`.

Here's my whole code:

```
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        int statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];


        NSError *e = nil;
//        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
        NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;

        NSLog(responseObject);
        NSLog(jsonArray);

        NSDictionary *testDic = (NSDictionary *)jsonArray[0];
        [testDic objectForKey:@"name"];

        if (!jsonArray) {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
        } else {
            for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
                NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
            }
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

**So, after all I'm just looking for a solution to parse my `JSONArray`.** I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356919/1331671), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962230/parse-json-response-with-afnetworking/21962445#21962445) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940101/how-to-extract-json-string-to-array) but didn't find a solution...

Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is the parsing error:

```
(<invalid>) <error: expected ']' error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: What is the error??  The `error:` parm is there for a reason.

Comment: And where is the output from that first NSLog??

Comment: -1 for failing to include NSLog output.

Comment: The NSError is not set and the jsonArray variable is not set as well. I updated my post with the parsing error I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I don't know what is different but now the code below is working:

```
 [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        int statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];
        NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSError *e = nil;
        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

        if(!jsonArray) {
           NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
        }else {
            for(NSDictionary *jsonDict in jsonArray) {

                for (id key in jsonDict) {
                    id value = [jsonDict objectForKey:key];

                    if([key isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
                       //create my object...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks @Yogesh Suthar for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to serialize that response because it is already serialized. Afnetworking library doing all these things internally. Just use

```
NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
```

isstead of

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

## Edit

To access inner values, for example to access `asdf`. Same for others as well.

```
NSDictionary *testDic = (NSDictionary *)jsonArray[0];
[testDic objectForKey:@"myattr"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access my inner json objects?

Comment: Sorry but I get `-[_NSInlineData objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d63440`

Comment: When I try this `jsonArray[0][@"myattr"];`

Comment: @Ale Now try edited answer. I am also using same code, it is working here. May be you are using old xcode.

Comment: Sorry but I get the error when I try to access the jsonArray[0] value. I use xcode 5.

Comment: The debugger shows me this from the jsonArray variable `Printing description of jsonArray:
<5b7b226e 616d6522 3a20224b 6174616c 6f672031 222c2022 66696c65 223a2022 68747470 3a2f2f6c 6f63616c ...`
Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @Ale Sorry for late reply. Do this thing 1) log `responseObject` and after that log `jsonArray`. 2) Check what output you get in these logs. If they are showing you json result than my code should work OR if it gives `<5b7b226e 616d6522 3a20224b 6174616c 6f672031 222c2022 66696c65 223a2022 68747470 3a2f2f6c 6f63616..` kind of response than you are getting NSData result. Kidly post your tried code in your question too.

Comment: thanks again, but now I get an error when I try to log the`responseObject`:   `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175789b0'`

Comment: @Ale For which code, kindly edit it in your question.